# Google charts angular data not displaying with custom cols

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, google-visualization

I have the following  array of javascript objects which I store in $scope.o

```
[{"id":"jimmy.cibby@redsss.com","label":"marc.cibby@redsss.com","type":"number","p":{}},{"id":"matthew.cibby@redsss.com","label":"matthew.cibby@redsss.com","type":"number","p":{}},{"id":"ari.grads@redsssdsss.com","label":"ari.grads@redsssdsss.com","type":"number","p":{}},{"id":"yup@redsssdsss.com","label":"yup@redsssdsss.com","type":"number","p":{}},{"id":"service@redsssdsss.com","label":"service@redsss.com","type":"number"}]
```

I then have the following setup for google charts:

```
$scope.data= {
  "type": "LineChart",
  "displayed": true,
  "data": {
    "cols":$scope.o,
    "rows": [
      {
        "c": [
          {
            "v": "January"
          },
          {
            "v": 19,
            "f": "42 items"
          },
          {
            "v": 12,
            "f": "Ony 12 items"
          },
          {
            "v": 7,
            "f": "7 servers"
          },
          {
            "v": 4
          },
          {"v": 5}
        ]
      },
      {
        "c": [
          {
            "v": "February"
          },
          {
            "v": 13
          },
          {
            "v": 1,
            "f": "1 unit (Out of stock this month)"
          },
          {
            "v": 12
          },
          {
            "v": 2
          },
          {
            "v": 2
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "c": [
          {
            "v": "March"
          },
          {
            "v": 24
          },
          {
            "v": 5
          },
          {
            "v": 11
          },
          {
            "v": 6
          },
          {
            "v":12
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "options": {
    "title": "some data",
    "tooltip": {trigger: "selection"},
    "isStacked": "true",
    "fill": 20,
    "displayExactValues": true,
    "chartArea": {width: "70%", height: "70%"},
    "vAxis": {
      "title": "data",
      "gridlines": {
        "count": 10
      }
    },
    "hAxis": {
      "title": "month"
    }
  },
  "formatters": {}
}




}]);
```

as you can see, all I have done to the sample app here: http://angular-google-chart.github.io/angular-google-chart/docs/latest/examples/multi-chart/
is change the columns to custom ones.

This kind of works- the legend pulls through the email address labels but the graph is empty with no data on it.

Any suggestions as to why this would happen?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it... I needed to add:
$scope.o.push({
                id: "month",
                label: "Month",
                type: "string"
            });
before the for loop. Rookie mistake!